# Subtract 'n' weeks from current date python

Tags: python, datetime

Subtracting 'n' days from current date could be done using:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
datetime.today() - timedelta(days=42)
```

Similarly, Is there a way to subtract 'n' weeks from current date in python

Comment: The `timedelta` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) would have offered a solution ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works..

```
datetime.today() - timedelta(weeks=42)
```